# prooving volume formular for simplices

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, simplex

let $ 1\leq n $ and $a_1,...,a_n \mathbb{R}^{+} $

A simplex $ \sigma $ ist given by $ \sigma := [0,a_1 e^1, .., a_n e^n ] $

I want to proove that

$$ \int_ {\sigma } 1= \frac{1}{n!} \prod_{j=1}^n  a_j $$

per induction.

first, I wanted to clarify the formula for lower n.

for $ n=1 , [0,e^1]$
you get $\int_{[0,e^1] }1= \int_0^{e^1} dx= e^1$
and set $e^1 = 1$

for $n=2, [0,e^1,e^2]$
you get
$\int_{[0,e^1,e^2]} 1 = \int_0^{e^1} \int_0^y dx dy = \frac{(e^1)^2}{2} $

for $ n=3, [0,e^1,e^2,e^3] $
you get, that
$ \int_{[0,e^1,e^2,e^3]} 1= \int_0^{e^1} \int_0^z \int_0^y dxdydz= \frac{(e^1)^3}{6} $

my question is also, if this is formally right? fells kinda wrong

so

$\int_{[0,e^1,e^n,e^{n+1}]} 1 = \int_0^{e1} \int_0^{x_{n+1}}....\int_0^{x_2} dx_1...dx_n dx_{n+1} $

$= \int_0^{e^1} \frac{1}{n!} x_{n+1}^n dx_{n+1} = \frac{e^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} $
and also set $ e^{n+1}=1$
..again..is this formally correct?

Comment: One way to do this is to construct a linear map that converts the simplex into the standard simplex and use the change of variables formula.

Comment: The reasonning behind the edit is perfectly fine, but the notations are a bit off. As far as I understand, your $e^i$ are vectors, so they shouldn't be included in your integral bounds. Basically, you should consider that $\int_{[0,e^1]} f = \int_0^1 f(x) dx$ is a definition.
Thus, you do not need to "set e^{n+1} = 1". (which I would consider nonsensical in this context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My two cents : first do the linear, diagonal change of variables $y_i=a_i * x_i$. The determinant of the jacobian matrix of this transformation is uniform, and its value is $\prod_i a_i$. The pre-image of your simplex is then the so-called "standard" simplex $\sigma_0 = [0,e^1,\dots,e^n]$, so that all you are left to prove is $\int_{\sigma_0} 1 = \frac{1}{n!}$. This is done using recurrence on the dimension $n$.

Edit : This is exactly what was already suggested in the comments, only a tiny bit more verbose.

Comment: thank you ! I have edited my question a bit. Can you expain how to do the diagonal change of variables in this case? Dont understand how to get there

Comment: @wondering1123 : Do you feel like your question has been solved ? If so, please consider accepting the answer.